# EIEIO Composition (exposing a slot of a contained object through own slot)

Tags: oop, emacs, lisp, elisp, composition

I have two EIEIO classes:

```
(defclass i-driver ()
  (;; more slots
   (exit-conditions
    :initarg :exit-conditions
    :initform nil
    :type list
    :documentation
    "Conditions to test in the main (while ...) expression"))
  :documentation "This class describes a single driver of `i-iterate' macro")
```

and:

```
(defclass i-spec ()
  ((exit-conditions
    :type list
    :reader i--get-exit-conditions
    :documentation
    "Conditions to test in the main (while ...) expression")
   ;; more slots
   (drivers
    :initform nil
    :type list
    :documentation 
    "This slot contains the list of all drivers used in this iteration macro"))
  :documentation "This class contains a specification of the
expansion of the `i-iterate' macro")
```

What I want to do:

- Expose `exit-conditions` field through `i-spec` class by aggregating it from a list of `i-driver` objects. My original idea was that I could define a reader, like so:

---

```
(defmethod i--get-exit-conditions ((spec i-spec))
  (with-slots ((ds drivers)) spec
    (let (result)
      (while ds
        (push (oref ds exit-conditions) result)
        (setq ds (cdr ds)))
      result)))
```

- I don't want to allocate the slot `exit-conditions` in `i-spec`, because it only needs to be stored in `i-driver`.
- I also want the slot to be read-only (it can be only modified by modifying the corresponding driver, but not through writing to the slot itself).

*PS. In case of copyrights claims, `i` in the names is for `iterate`, it's not for whatever Wozniak used it in Apple's products :)*

EDIT:

Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
(defmethod i-aggregate-property ((spec i-spec) property &optional extractor)
  (with-slots (drivers) spec
    (let ((ds drivers)result)
      (while ds
        (if extractor
            (setq result
                  (funcall extractor (slot-value (car ds) property) result))
          (push (slot-value (car ds) property) result))
        (setq ds (cdr ds))) result)))
```

And here's the ugly look:

```
(defmacro i-iterate (&rest specs)
  (let ((spec (i--parse-specs specs)))
    (with-slots (body result) spec
      (let* ((exit-conditions
              (i-aggregate-property spec 'exit-conditions #'append))
             (catch-conditions
              (i-aggregate-property spec 'catch-conditions #'append))
             (variables
              (i-aggregate-property spec 'variables #'append))
             (actions
              (i-aggregate-property spec 'actions #'append))
             (econds
              (cond
               ((cdr exit-conditions)
                (append '(and) (nreverse exit-conditions)))
               (exit-conditions (car exit-conditions))
               (t t)))
             (vars (nreverse variables))
             (body (append actions (nreverse body))))
        (cond
         ((and catch-conditions vars)
          (append catch-conditions
                  (list
                   `(let* (,@vars)
                      (while ,econds ,@body) result))))
         (catch-conditions
          (append catch-conditions
                  (list
                   `(while ,econds ,@body) result)))
         (variables
          `(let* (,@vars)
             (while ,econds ,@body) ,result))
         (t `(progn (while ,econds ,@body) ,result)))))))
```

I could add a macro to hide this repetitive calls and have something like `with-slots`, but I'd be much happier, if I didn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just define a generic function `exit-conditions` specified on `i-spec` instead of a slot?